# Как сделать такую клавиатуру?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Где можно найти исходники этой клавиатуры. Не могу найти ни как.

А самому сделать такую клаву думаю проблематично. Надо в точь точь такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/

Answer (score 2):

Исходники внутренних приложений Android можешь найти тут:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/
```

Касательно вашего вопроса, у вас приложение Phone:
По этой ссылке вы сможете скачать репозиторий приложения Phone:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone
```

Находите нужный коммит и используйте исходники.

К примеру:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone
git checkout 32d4187ddfddde7
```

В итоге будет проект с исходными файлами.

Comment: Я дал прямую ссылку до исходов клавиатуры, для каких целей, вы, даете ссылку на все исходники `android`? Не понятно.

Comment: @and если вы внимательно посмотрите, ссылка ведет на репозиторий приложения phone, а не всех исходников Android.
По этой ссылке пользователь может найти ветку с нужной версий и стилем клавиатуры.